# Why TFontDialog gives less fonts than Screen.Fonts?

Tags: windows, delphi, fonts, wordpad

I am wondering why TFontDialog gives less fonts than Screen.Fonts? (For example, the Arial* font, the Comic font, etc, does not show in TFontDialog)

It also seems that the font list given by TFontDialog is the same as WordPad, whereas the font list given by Screen.Fonts is basically the same as Word.

Thank you very much for your insights!

PS:
  Delphi XE,
  Windows 7

PS: related SO topics:

1. [Too many fonts when enumerating with EnumFontFamiliesEx function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253827/too-many-fonts-when-enumerating-with-enumfontfamiliesex-function)
2. [Finding System Fonts with Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401915/finding-system-fonts-with-delphi?rq=1)
3. [How to use external fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305344/how-to-use-external-fonts?rq=1)

PS: related web pages:

1. [TFontDialog to show all Fonts @ borland.newsgroups.archived](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.nativeapi.win32/200710/0710039059.html)
2. [TFontDialog to show all Fonts @ delphigroups](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/2/358057.html)

[image: sys]
[image: app]

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    lst1: TListBox;
    dlgFont1: TFontDialog;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lst1.Items.AddStrings(Screen.Fonts);
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dlgFont1.Device := fdBoth;
  if dlgFont1.Execute then
  begin

  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: There's a chance that you get different results using different values for dlgFont1.Device. Try fdScreen and fdPrinter and then compare the lists again.

Comment: @Doug The `Device` property is ignored on modern Windows (I think)

Comment: @Doug No difference using different values for dlgFont1.Device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Screen.Fonts` returns all installed fonts, including hidden fonts as administrated in *Registry\HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Font Management\Inactive Fonts*. ([Source](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/FontFilter/)) Apparently, `TFontDialog` does not display these hidden fonts.

Furthermore, some fonts listed in `Screen.Fonts` are not mentioned in the *Font* combo box of `TFontDialog`, but are added to the *Font style* combo box. Take *Arial* for example: the Font style lists 10 items, which seems to be the combination of the fonts *Arial*, *Arial Black* and *Arial Narrow*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful comments! I can now manipulate that registry key, OR walk through the control panel, to show my favorite fonts in TFontDialog & WordPad! :)

Answer (score 2):

Different APIs, different results.  `Screen.Fonts` uses `EnumFontFamiliesEx()`, which returns all installed fonts.  `TFontDialog` uses `ChooseFont()` instead, which only displays the fonts that are compatible with the `TFontDialog.Font` and `TFontDialog.Options` properties.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! Could you help to elaborate `compatible with TFontDialog.Font` and `TFontDialog.Options`? I mean, is it possible to have TFontDialog give the same as Screen.Fonts suggests?