# Delphi - Retrieve .Fon font name from a specified file

Tags: delphi, fonts

What i want is a Delphi code that retrieve the name from .fon font file, 
I did a Google search but it went to 0.

to be clear:
Example: i have font:
the file name + path: C:\joker_let.fon
the font real name is: 'Joker LET 1.0'

What I did so far:

```
Function GetFONFontName(FontFile: String): String;
var FS : TMemoryStream;
    FontName: Array of Char;
Begin
  Result:= '';
  FS := TMemoryStream.Create();
  Try
    FS.LoadFromFile(FontFile);
    SetLength(FontName, FS.Size);
    FS.ReadBuffer(FontName[0], FS.Size);
    Result:= String( FontName);
    Result:= Copy(Result, Pos('FONTRES', Result)+8, 250);
    Result:= Copy(Result, Pos(':', Result)+141, 60);
    Result:= Copy(Result, 1, Pos(#0, Result)-1);
    Result:= Trim(Result);
  Finally
    FS.Free;
  End;
End;
```

But this function not working as it should be, 
because the font name its not stored in same place in all .fon files.
if i give the font in the example i will get its name; but if i just give another font 
i not get its name correctly or it went to nothing just ''.
so i need something else that retrieve the .fon name in each file.

- I did another Google search to get the .fon file structure but i didn't find something useful
  i found only that there is two types: PE and ZE.
  to be specified i want the PE type (Portable Executable = MZ).
  since i didn't find a detailed information about the .fon PE Type so i did
  that stupid

> Function GetFONFontName(FontFile: String): String;
>   to do a temporary solution.

hope i was clear.
sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

This question was posed before here: [How do I get the font name from a font file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381537/how-do-i-get-the-font-name-from-a-font-file).  Looks like you can use the GetFontResourceInfo Win API.